# Loop through a list of names with textillate

Tags: jquery, css, loops

What I want to achieve is a div or "box" with text in it, this text should slide in from the right and out to the left, pausing inside the box for a second or two.
The text should also change, let's say I want to loop through this list:
Name 1
Name 2
Name 3
Then start over from the first entry.

I am terrible at javascript and could use some sort of "step by step" guidance.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you know the basics of jquery? Lets say, do you know how to change the `text` of a `div` with id `myDiv` with jquery?

Comment: you will need to learn the basics first. http://www.codecademy.com/dashboard

Comment: BatuZet I used too, I should be able to that much.
@Sionnach733 Thanks, I'l have a look at it :)